# Table with hidden child rows using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, html-table

My requirement:

[image]

[image]

I mean when I click plus symbol table will show child rows.
I tried the following code:

```
 $this->view->getallrelease = $this->model->getAllrelease($id);
 $this->view->getsprint[]=$this->model->GetAllsprint($relseid);
```

I have releases and sprints under releases, so when I click releases it will show all sprints under it as child table.
**View page**

```
<tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row<?php echo $i; ?>" data-target=".row<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['release_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo format_date($details['release_creation_date']); ?></td>  
    <td> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" onclick="appendId(<?php echo $details['release_id']?>,'<?php echo $date[0]?>')"><img src="http://localhost/manage/public/img/new_sprint.png"  border="0"/></a></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($this->getallrelease as $details):?>

    <tr class="collapse row<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <td>- child row<?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td>data<?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td>data<?php echo $i; ?></td>  
        <td>data<?php echo $i; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php $i++;endforeach; endforeach;endif;?>
```

but I didn't get expected output `.collapsing` working fine.

**[image: output]**

`$i` is increasing I got child row4 instead of child row2 and child7 instead of child 3. so i got $i=1 4 7 instead of 1 2 3 Please help me.

Comment: are you using framwork ?

Comment: @TarangP just Mvc

Comment: "_but its not working_" What does that mean? Collapsing doesn't work? Is the wrong subsection collapsed? No errors in your console? Do you have javascript anywhere that handles collapsing?

Comment: @kerbholz sorry..i have update my codes

Comment: Take a look at the source and make sure all `$i`s are correctly incremented, (looks like it gets incremented for every `<tr>`, should be every second `<tr>`) and that every collapse triggers the correct collapsible.